# Bootstrap modal lightbox showing scrollbar background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 in my project. I have a modal lightbox in my page there is some content in it. I just put `height: 300px` and `overflow-y: scroll` in it. But it is showing scrollbar background all the time even when the content height is below 300px. How can i fix this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `overflow-y: auto;` instead of `overflow-y:scroll;`
(when auto is use it showing the scrollbar only when it need and not all the time)